# How to get rupees and paise in separate columns from the amount

Tags: php, mysql, money-format

The database value for my project will be TOTAL AMOUNT like "1500.45". What I want is to separate the column for Rupees & Paise. 1500 should be under Rupees column, and paise 45 should be under paise column. How to do that?

Output should be like this

```
|amount |       | rupees | paise |
|1500.45|   ==> | 1500   | 45    |
```

Comment: This question is not answerable, because you left out the data and the query.  Please include both.

Comment: Explode on the `.` and then assign the values as needed? Will there always only be one `.` in the string? Can use `rtrim` to remove the trailing characters after `45`. If the format isn't consistent dont use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two need for two decimal points then use the following code :

```
$amount = 1500.45; // if it is a string then convert it into decimal
$rupee = floor($amount);
$paise = (int)($amount - $rupee)*100; // and set pricision two
echo $rupee.'<br/>';
echo $paise;
```

and if it string or decimal any type then you can use the code as follows :

```
$amount = 1500.45;
$rupee = explode('.',$amount)[0];
echo $rupee.'<br/>';
echo explode('.',$amount)[1];
```

Comment: $paise = (int)(($amount - $rupee)*100);

Answer (score 2):

simply using split comment to separate rupees and paise..

```html
 <?

$RS=2300.75;

$df=split("[.]",$RS);

echo "rupees ".$df[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "paise ".$df[1];


?>
```

for more details see the link [php code for rupees and paise](http://www.php77.in/how-to-get-rupees-and-paise-in-separate-columns-from-the-amount/)

Answer (score 1):

Use explode() Function .

```
explode(".",your amount)
```

explode will separate your amount to get Rupees & Paise .
You will get separated value in array using that array you can store bot values in separate columns .

Answer (score 0):

use **SUBSTRING_INDEX()** to split values in mysql then update

```
 UPDATE `table` SET `rupees`=SUBSTRING_INDEX(`amount`,'.',1),`paise`=SUBSTRING_INDEX(`amount`,'.',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select substring_index('amount', '.', 1) as rupees, substring_index('amount', '.', -1) as paise;
```